# Control is not switched to iframe if i run test case in firefox: Protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to run my script (`Protractor`) in firefox.
There is as iframe on page and i need to click on a link in that iframe. That click redirects to new tab and i need to switch in that tab too.
but by code that click is not working

I tried to put some wait till the link is clickable but its not working

```
        var announcementsGadget = gadget.getAnnouncementGadget();
        expect(announcementsGadget.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

        var iframe = gadget.getGadgetbyiFrame(announcementsGadget);
        browser.switchTo().frame(iframe.getWebElement());

        var allAnnouncements = gadget.getAllAnnouncementGadget();
        allAnnouncements.click().then(function() {

            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
                browser.sleep(4000)
                browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function() {
                    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual');
                    browser.sleep(sleep_interval);
                    browser.close();
                });

                browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
                browser.sleep(5000);
            });
        });
```

It should click on the `allAnnouncements` Link and switch to a new tab

Comment: May i know the reason of -1 and why it is unclear. I tried to fix this but its not happening.

Answer (score 0):

**If there are multi iframe, you can use :**

```
 browser.switchTo().frame(0);
```

> to switch to first iframe

and use :

```
browser.switchTo().frame(1);
```

> to switch to second iframe

**If there is an iframe in html**, you also can use  `browser.switchTo().frame(0);` to switch to that iframe.

> Then, you can click the link what you want. ex: `driver.findElement(by.tagName('a')).click();`
>
> After that, you must to switch to out that iframe by :

```
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

> Then now new tab has opened on browser, and you can switch to new tab, and do what you want.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, Actually above code is working in chrome, the problem is on Firefox. It's not working on Firefox browser

Comment: i had test with iframe and it was working in both browser. what error did you get ?

Comment: Well in my case, there are multiple iframes on page so i am passing the reference of  desired iframe 
i.e.
var iframe = gadget.getGadgetbyiFrame(announcementsGadget);
browser.switchTo().frame(iframe.getWebElement());

but i am not able to perform allAnnouncements.click() which should open a new tab and facing error

Comment: Message:
    Failed: missing field `handle` at line 1 column 2
  Stack:
    InvalidArgumentError: missing field `handle` at line 1 column 2

From: Task: WebDriver.switchTo().window(undefined)

Comment: When you use **browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function() {}** working space of protractor will switch to **window(handles[1])** . In **window handles[1]** you can't interact to outside of **window handles[1]**, protractor just have to work in **window handles[1]** . So If you want to switch out from **window(handles[1])** you must to do it in **.then(function(){})**, **browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function() {}** . After that, you can switch to other window handles .

Comment: Hi @AquariusPotter, Thank you for your response but problem is here i am not able to click on hyperlink inside the frame. if i would able to click on hyperlink  i can switch to new window easily. help help me in this

Comment: just try : 
`browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function() { //do what you want //exit frame browser.switchTo().defaultContent(); }`

Comment: Hi,I did but for new window i have to click on the hyperlink present in that iframe. And its not happening. Code is mentioned in initial question